# GRIB2 weather data into ArcGIS

Tags: r, arcgis, grib

I'm having troubles getting data from the GRIB2 file format into a useable format for plotting in ArcGIS.

I'm using R and the rgdal package to import the data into R but am having troubles outputting any useful data to ArcGIS. I tried exporting to a GEOTIFF, but all the values were scraped for some reason.

Does anyone have a suggested workflow for data like this? Or suggestions on how to address this challenge?

Thanks